# How to calculate IDFT this signal?

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals, deconvolution

$X(jw) = 1 + \frac {jw+3}{jw+4}$  what is the IDFT of this signal?

Comment: Do a little bit of research - google, for example. Takes a minute to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: if you know this solution write here, if you don't know don't write. Why is this ego? What is the difference write to here or research on google?

Comment: you have to try to be helpful.

Comment: Ego ?! :D Are you nuts ? The difference is the fact you, as it looks like, did not spend a minute researching. Instead you are asking to just give it to you. You have to show some effort. Yes, you too have to try to be helpful - try to be helpful to yourself ;)

Comment: I will write to you as we are both part of this community. Have a nice day !

Comment: @TunahanÇATAK: Please be more polite. You are being rude to other DSP.SE participants. Your question comes across as if you could not be bothered to do any work yourself (which others have pointed out).  Please say what you've tried (by editing your question), so we can help you.

Comment: don't Matlab now, but the alternative form could help using transformation table. take a look at


http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28+1+%2B+%28jw%2B3%29%2F%28jw%2B4%29%29

Answer (score -2, accepted):

IF w refers to set of frequencies i assume that you can put it on Matlab and get the results,for sure.

Comment: yes i know it but i need to this signal equation x(t) = ...?

Comment: If i understand well,you need to transfer your signal to the back to the time domain.So you do this by using the formula of IDFT and plugging in,in the X(w) part of it your signal (as you have it displayed up) for different frequency values.You can find the equation of the inverse DFT by having a quick look online (like wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).If you need an example you can find in many books step by step ones.Is it the complex number you have confusing you?

Comment: @GiwrgosRizeakos I am not the downvoter, but I think the OP asked for a analytic IDFT expression, and what you provided here is a numerical one. I guess that's why the downvote comes.

Comment: It was my fault trying to help from the begining